# Is this sentence proper grammar?

Tags: phrases

Is this sentence using proper grammar? - "The money was and is not a loan."

Comment: The money was (and is) not a loan.  The money was, and is, not a loan.  The money was not, and is not, a loan.

Comment: Please never just ask “Is this correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to say that the money was not taken on loan, and still now it is not.
So the correct sentence is " The money was not, and is not a loan "

Comment: Would you put another comma after the second **not** ?

Comment: Yes .. was not, and is not, a loan.

Comment: @stew I would, but I'm a serial comma user.

Comment: @Josh61 You might want to update your answer rather than amend it via comments.

Answer (score 0):

"The money was and is not a loan."

as with all instances of "and", you can expand the sentence to better understand its meaning. But first let's get rid of the "not" to make things simpler (we can add it back later)

"The money was and is a loan"

Both verbs "was" and "is" require a subject and an object, so "money" must act as a subject for both and "loan" as an object for both:

The money was a loan. The money is a loan.

Now let's add "not" back:
"not" is added to "be" to form the negative. Due to the "and" it has to be added to both verbs:

"The money [was not] a loan. The money [is not] a loan"

you can add commas to make it more understandable by imitating natural pauses as when spoken: "The money was, and is, not a loan"